# json filter in creating a jinja2 template

Tags: json, ansible, jinja2

am trying to create my 1st jinja2 template that extracts a field from a json string as am trying to create DHCP reserveration file.

here is an example inventory feed.

I would like to select the value from the mac address to use as a value as jinja2 value for a field for the interface that matches the ansible host. which could be in any postion on the interfaces.

how would I go about it

```
 "TEST": {
                "ansible_host": "192.171.130.8",
                "interfaces": [
                    {
                        "ip_addresses": [
                            {
                                "address": "192.171.130.8/32",
                            }
                        ],
                        "mac_address": "C8-F1-13-78-9E-E7"
                        
                    },
                    {
                        "ip_addresses": [
                            {
                                "address": "192.171.130.80/32",
                            }
                        ],
                        "mac_address": "85-9F-76-AE-57-10"
                        
                    }
                ],
                
               
         }
```

so I would like to doe something like

{{ hostvars[host].interfaces.[ip_addresses.address = ansible_host].mac_address }}

but am not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a good candidate for the [`json_query` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-json-data-json-queries). My first thought was that this should work:

```
hostvars[host].interfaces | json_query("[?ip_addresses[].address == '192.171.130.8/32']")
```

But that returns an empty list. The following is a bit more verbose, but produces the expected result:

```
hostvars[host].interfaces|json_query("[?ip_addresses[].address | contains(@, '192.171.130.8/32')]")
```

In a playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    TEST: {
      "ansible_host": "192.171.130.8",
      "interfaces": [
        {
          "ip_addresses": [
            {
              "address": "192.171.130.8/32",
              }
              ],
          "mac_address": "C8-F1-13-78-9E-E7"

          },
          {
            "ip_addresses": [
              {
                "address": "192.171.130.80/32",
                }
                ],
            "mac_address": "85-9F-76-AE-57-10"

            }
            ],


          }
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: >-
          {{ TEST.interfaces | json_query("[?ip_addresses[].address | contains(@, '192.171.130.8/32')]") }}
```

NB: Watch your quoting; you'll note that here I've used the YAML folding quote operating (`>`) because the expression contains both double quotes and single quotes, so putting either of those around the outside would mean escaping quotes inside the expression.

Running the above playbook produces:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "ip_addresses": [
                {
                    "address": "192.171.130.8/32"
                }
            ],
            "mac_address": "C8-F1-13-78-9E-E7"
        }
    ]
}
```

---

Since you've got the desired address in a variable (`ansible_host`), you would write instead:

```
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: >-
          {{
            hostvars[host].interfaces | json_query("[?ip_addresses[].address | contains(@, '%s/32')]" % ansible_host)
          }}
```

---

Our expression returns a list containing a single dictionary. If you want the `mac_address` field, treat the result just like any other Ansible array variable:

```
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: >-
          {{
          (
            hostvars[host].interfaces |
            json_query("[?ip_addresses[].address | contains(@, '%s/32')]" % ansible_host)
          ).0.mac_address
          }}
```

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to get just the `mac_address` field.

Comment: thanks with your help and a bit of playing am to ` tasks: - debug: msg: >- {{ hostvars[host].interfaces | json_query("[?ip_addresses[].address | contains(@, '%s/32')]" % hostvars[host].ansible_host) }} ` this returns whole array element as above now how can I just pick the mac_address field as the output?

Comment: ok thank you 
that gets me to 

TASK [Prints json] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "\"AE:AE:52:07:E9:14\""
}

so I just need to work out how to lose the \" in but you got me what I was after.

Answer (score 1):

Create the dictionary from the MAC addresses and lists of IPs

```yaml
  mac_ip_raw: "{{ dict(interfaces|json_query(mac_ip_query)) }}"
  mac_ip_query: '[].[mac_address, ip_addresses[].address]'
```

gives

```yaml
  mac_ip_raw:
    85-9F-76-AE-57-10:
    - 192.171.130.80/32
    C8-F1-13-78-9E-E7:
    - 192.171.130.8/32
```

Get rid of the masks

```yaml
  mac_ip: "{{ dict(mac_ip_raw.keys()|
                   zip(mac_ip_raw.values()|
                       map('map', 'split', '/')|
                       map('map', 'first'))) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  mac_ip:
    85-9F-76-AE-57-10:
    - 192.171.130.80
    C8-F1-13-78-9E-E7:
    - 192.171.130.8
```

Now, test which list contains the IP

```yaml
  my_mac: "{{ mac_ip|dict2items|
              selectattr('value', 'contains', ansible_host)|
              map(attribute='key')|first }}"
```

gives the expected result

```yaml
  my_mac: C8-F1-13-78-9E-E7
```

---

Example of a complete project for testing

```bash
shell> tree .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── hosts
├── host_vars
│   └── srv1
│       └── interfaces.json
└── pb.yml

2 directories, 4 files
```

```ini
shell> cat ansible.cfg 
[defaults]
gathering = explicit
collections_path = $HOME/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/
inventory = $PWD/hosts
roles_path = $PWD/roles
retry_files_enabled = false
stdout_callback = yaml
```

```ini
shell> cat hosts
srv1 ansible_host=192.171.130.8
```

```
shell> cat host_vars/srv1/interfaces.json 
{
  "interfaces":
    [
        {
            "ip_addresses": [
                {
                    "address": "192.171.130.8/32"
                }
            ],
            "mac_address": "C8-F1-13-78-9E-E7"
        },
        {
            "ip_addresses": [
                {
                    "address": "192.171.130.80/32"
                }
            ],
            "mac_address": "85-9F-76-AE-57-10"
        }
    ]
}
```

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: all

  vars:

    mac_ip_raw: "{{ dict(interfaces|json_query(mac_ip_query)) }}"
    mac_ip_query: '[].[mac_address, ip_addresses[].address]'
    mac_ip: "{{ dict(mac_ip_raw.keys()|
                     zip(mac_ip_raw.values()|
                         map('map', 'split', '/')|
                         map('map', 'first'))) }}"
    my_mac: "{{ mac_ip|dict2items|
                selectattr('value', 'contains', ansible_host)|
                map(attribute='key')|first }}"
    
  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: ansible_host
    - debug:
        var: interfaces
    - debug:
        var: mac_ip_raw
    - debug:
        var: mac_ip
    - debug:
        var: my_mac
```